# need explanation of the _.bindAll() function from Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've been learning some backbone.js and I've seen plenty of instances where `_.bindAll()` is used. I have read through the entire backbone.js and underscore.js documentation page to try to get a sense of what it does, but I still am very fuzzy as to what it does. Here is underscore's explanation:

> ```
> _.bindAll(object, [*methodNames])
> ```
>
> Binds a number of methods on the
>   object, specified by methodNames, to
>   be run in the context of that object
>   whenever they are invoked. Very handy
>   for binding functions that are going
>   to be used as event handlers, which
>   would otherwise be invoked with a
>   fairly useless this. If no methodNames
>   are provided, all of the object's
>   function properties will be bound to
>   it.
>
> ```
> var buttonView = {
>   label   : 'underscore',
>   onClick : function(){ alert('clicked: ' + this.label); },
>   onHover : function(){ console.log('hovering: ' + this.label); }
> };
>
> _.bindAll(buttonView);
>
> jQuery('#underscore_button').bind('click', buttonView.onClick);
> => When the button is clicked, this.label will have the correct value...
> ```

If you can help out here by giving another example perhaps or some verbal explanation, anything would be appreciated. I tried to search for more tutorials or examples, but nil turn up that serve what I needed. Most people seem to just know what it does automatically...

Comment: Great explanation: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```js
var Cow = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Cow.prototype.moo = function() {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += this.name + ' moos' + '<br>';
}

var cow1 = new Cow('alice');
var cow2 = new Cow('bob');

cow1.moo(); // alice moos
cow2.moo(); // bob moos

var func = cow1.moo;
func(); // not what you expect since the function is called with this===window
_.bindAll(cow1, 'moo');
func = cow1.moo;
func(); // alice moos
```

```html
<div id="output" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately the actual "bind all" functionality only works on functions right on the object. To include a function that is defined on the prototype you need to pass those function names explicitely as additional arguments to `_.bindAll()`.

Anyway, you wanted an explanation: Basically it allows you to replace a function on an object with a function that has the same name and behaviour, but is also bound to that object, so `this === theObject` even without calling it as a method (`theObject.method()`).

Comment: @ThiefMaster "pass those function names explicitely as additional arguments to _.bindAll()."
Sorry, still learning from your example and try to figure out its implications here: so you say that the functions defined on prototype are not automatically be bound with the object under _.bindAll  and if one were to achieve this, one needs to feed the first parameter with the object; the second paramter the function name IF that function was defined on the prototype?

Comment: [This blog post by Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/) explains `this` in JavaScript very well.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest explanation as for me is the next:

```
initialize:function () { //backbone initialize function
    this.model.on("change",this.render); //doesn't work because of the wrong context - in such a way we are searching for a render method in the window object  
    this.model.on("change",this.render,this); //works fine
    //or 
    _.bindAll(this,'render');
    this.model.on("change",this.render); //now works fine
    //after  _.bindAll we can use short callback names in model event bindings
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="underscore_button"/>

<script>
var buttonView = {
    id     : 'underscore',
    onClick: function () {console.log('clicked: ' + this.id)},
    onHover: function () {console.log('hovering: ' + this.id)}
}
_.bindAll(buttonView, 'onClick')
$('#underscore_button').click(buttonView.onClick)
$('#underscore_button').hover(buttonView.onHover)
</script>
```