# bindAll() method of underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, this

In `underscore` documentation bindAll method does the following:

```
_.bindAll(object, *methodNames) // syntax

var buttonView = {
  label  : 'underscore',
  onClick: function(){ alert('clicked: ' + this.label); },
  onHover: function(){ console.log('hovering: ' + this.label); }
};
_.bindAll(buttonView, 'onClick', 'onHover');
// When the button is clicked, this.label will have the correct value.
jQuery('#underscore_button').bind('click', buttonView.onClick);
```

Now bindAll() method binds a number of methods on the object, specified by methodNames, to be run in the context of that object whenever they are invoked. Now is it really necessary to call bindAll() on the above example??

I think calling `buttonView.onClick` will automatically bind `this` keyword to `buttonView` isn't it??

Comment: Yes, `buttonView.onClick()` would do, but you're not calling `buttonView.onClick`, are you?

Comment: no, i am not calling `buttonView.onClick()` but  calling `buttonView.onClick` also invoke a function, so will it not bind `this` keyword??

Comment: No, there is no call/invocation in your code. jQuerys event handling system would call the function that you passed, and with the DOM element as the `this` context.

Comment: so `click` event on `#underscore_button` invokes it that means...so this is bind to that object...is it??

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582059/need-explanation-of-the-bindall-function-from-underscore-js -- in particular where there is a comment on the OP that says _Great Explanation_ with a link and also has a bunch of comment upvotes.

Comment: Here's the link from the _Great Explanation_ comment: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html